# How to connect a MySQL database from Node.js Prisma running on Google Cloud Run to Cloud SQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-cloud-sql, prisma, google-cloud-run

I am currently working on a Node.js project utilizing Prisma to interact with a MySQL database. The application is deployed on Google Cloud Run, and the database resides in Google Cloud SQL.

Here's a snippet of my schema.prisma file:

```
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets   = ["native"]
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

I've set up the DATABASE_URL in my Cloud Run environment variables, but I'm struggling to connect to the Cloud SQL database. The application works fine locally, but I keep receiving connection errors when deploying to Cloud Run.

I have already ensured that Cloud Run's service account has the required permissions to access Cloud SQL, and I've also tried various connection strings with no luck.

Here's the error message I receive:

> Error connecting to the database: PrismaClientInitializationError: The
> provided database string is invalid. Error parsing connection string:
> empty host in database URL. Please refer to the documentation in
> https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/database-reference/connection-urls
> for constructing a correct connection string. In some cases, certain
> characters must be escaped. Please check the string for any illegal
> characters.

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://USER:PASSWORD@/DATABASE?socket=/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME
```

How should I properly configure the connection between Prisma in Cloud Run and Cloud SQL?
Is there any specific firewall or connection settings that need to be handled for this setup?
Are there any best practices for securing this connection?
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you enable a Cloud SQL integration on Cloud Run?

Comment: What is Cloud SQL integration on Cloud Run? I choose  Cloud SQL connections on Cloud Run.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the issue you are facing related to the port number used for Cloud SQL. The correct port number is 3307, not 3306. Here's how you can update your DATABASE_URL to reflect this:

```
mysql://USER:PASSWORD@localhost:3307/DATABASE?socket=/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME
```

Replace USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE, and INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME with your respective credentials and connection information.

Once you update the connection string with the correct port, it should work as expected.

Comment: I don't believe you need to specify a port if you are connecting via unix sockets. Per the [Prisma docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/mysql#connecting-via-sockets) you just need to specify localhost (no port needed). I believe you were just missing the localhost piece in your original post.

You should try the following URL and see if it works: `mysql://USER:PASSWORD@localhost/DATABASE?socket=/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME`